# Python specifying file location directory

Tags: python, opencv, python-import

I am using Python 64 bit IDLE on Windows 7 machine to attempt to write a script for opencv machine learning. Im trying to figure out why my code below cannot find the directory where my picture files are located on my Windows PC.

Is there a better way to do this? Nothing happens in the shell output in IDLE and I was hoping the print function would work.

I have the .py files in a folder called faces on my C:drive, as shown below.
**C:\Users\ben\Documents\Python\opencv\Faces\images\ben**

And the picture files are located in **Faces\images\ben**

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pickle

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
image_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "images")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("png") or file.endswith("JPEG"):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            label = os.path.basename(root).replace(" ", "-").lower()
            print(path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your python files are in

```
C:\Users\ben\Documents\Python\opencv\Faces
```

and images are in

```
C:\Users\ben\Documents\Python\opencv\Faces\images\ben
```

then:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
image_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "images", "ben")
```

If still giving problems, try to build the image_dir manually:

```
image_dir = "%s\%s\%s"%(BASE_DIR, "images", "ben")
```

Answer (score 0):

since, your code file is placed in Faces folder
images path will be as follows

```
loc = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"images"),"ben")
```